# Remove query strings from HTTP response status code 301 url redirections

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My `.htaccess` file contains Rewrite URLs and HTTP response status code 301 url redirections. When I test the redirections, it adds the query string values from the old url to the end of the redirected url. How can I stop this?

My htaccess looks like this.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Redirect 301 /old-site/tees~1-c/blue~123-p.html test.mydomain.com/tees~1-c/blue~123-p.html
Redirect 301 /old-site/tees~1-c.html test.mydomain.com/tees~1-c.html
Redirect 301 /old-site/content/about.html test.mydomain.com/content/about.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)~(.+)-c/(.+)~(.+)-p\.html?$ product.php?cde=$1&cid=$2&pde=$3&pid=$4 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+)~(.+)-c\.html?$ category.php?cde=$1&cid=$2&ref=%3&srt=%4&sta=%5&ppa=%6 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^content/(.+)\.html?$ info.php?seo=$1&sta=%1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated at the [mod_alias doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

> If the client requests http://example.com/service/foo.txt, it will be
>   told to access http://foo2.example.com/service/foo.txt instead. This
>   includes requests with GET parameters, such as
>   http://example.com/service/foo.pl?q=23&a=42, it will be redirected to
>   http://foo2.example.com/service/foo.pl?q=23&a=42

You can change your **Redirec 301** to Rewrite rules:

Instead of:

```
Redirect 301 /old-site/tees~1-c/blue~123-p.html test.mydomain.com/tees~1-c/blue~123-p.html
Redirect 301 /old-site/tees~1-c.html test.mydomain.com/tees~1-c.html
Redirect 301 /old-site/content/about.html test.mydomain.com/content/about.html
```

Use:

```
RewriteRule /old-site/tees~1-c.html test.mydomain.com/tees~1-c.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule /old-site/tees~1-c.html test.mydomain.com/tees~1-c.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule /old-site/content/about.html test.mydomain.com/content/about.html [L,R=301]
```

If you don't include the QSA flag, NO query param is added to the rewrited url